# Updating value of an attribute in a class

Tags: java, class

I have the following code in Card.java class:

```
public class Card{
private String card,notation;
private int frequency,removed,dealt;

public Card(String notation,String card){
    this.notation = notation;
    this.card = card;
}

public String getCard(){
    return card;
}

public void setFrequency(int frequency){
    this.frequency = frequency;
}

public int getFrequency(){
    return frequency;
}

}
```

and the following code in Cardstack.java:

```
public class Cardstack{

private static ArrayList<Card> cardstack = new ArrayList<>();

public boolean addToStack(Card card){
    for(Card c: cardstack){
        if(c.getCard().equals(card.getCard())){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return cardstack.add(card);
}

public void shuffleStack(){
    Collections.shuffle(cardstack);
}

public ArrayList<Card> getCards() {
    return cardstack;
}

}
```

Now, whenever i have to add cards from a dice notation, say 2d3, i do the following:

```
Cardstack stack = new Cardstack();
for(i=2;i<=6;i++){
    Card card = new Card("2d3",""+i);
    stack.add(card);
}
```

It works fine until I have to update the frequency of the card. Suppose, if I have to now update the frequency of the card "3" of the dice "2d3" (which is already added in the stack), how do i do it? (keep in mind that, card "3" of dice "2d3" is a different card from card "3" of a different dice, say "2d4")

Comment: It appears that you would obtain the appropriate `Card` and invoke its `setFrequency()` method with the appropriate argument.  Perhaps you would use that  `Card`'s `getFrequency()` method to determine what argument is needed.  That seems straightforward, so what are you really asking?

Comment: `getFrequency()` and `setFrequency()` for the selected card will do what you are looking for.

Comment: Can you explain what the dice notation is? Because I think you want to update the `card` field when the frequency changes, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is now you have to go trough the entire ArrayList

```
for(Card c: cards){
...
}
```

to find the matching Card using the equals method from Card (you have to override it).

More elegant solution would be to use a HashMap (a,b) where a = card.notation, then you could lookup the card by hashmap.get(card notation) to update the frequency.

You could then just keep the Keys (card notation) as the actual stack and shuffle those:
List keys = new ArrayList(map.keySet());
Collections.shuffle(keys);

Answer (score -1):

By default the equals() method compares all member variables, so here also the frequency. Is this what you want?

If the card is equal to another only when its card and notation variables are the same, then you have to override the default equals method.

Comment: When you suggest to override equals(), please also mention that you should override hashCode(). NEVER override equals() except you know, what you're doing. This can lead to all kinds of weird side effects. Google: hashCode() equals() contract.

Comment: You are right, but why to vote down my comment just because of that?

Comment: Because at this point your answer is bad advice and using it would lead to a bad solution that might introduce hard to track down bugs.

Comment: I think you are unfair to me. Is the idea wrong or correct? If it is the correct solution to the given problem, why you vote me down? I appreciate your comment, but you are denying my solution because of a small omission (important, that is true, but still loosely relevant to the problem).

Comment: There's a lot of things wrong with your answer. First of all the default (meaning Object's) equals() does not compare all members, but is just "return (this == obj);". This is documented BTW in the JavaDocs of Object.equals(). So equals by default only returns true, if the object reference is the same. Second: Simply implementing your answer will break basic Java functionality by breaking the equals() hashCode() contract - see their JavaDocs. From the question I'm guessing that OP is not an experienced programmer, so to make your answer a good one, you should at least mention said subtleties.